# Drawing family tree with `genealogytree`

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, genealogytree, genealogy

I'm trying to create a version of the image below using the [`genealogytree`](https://ctan.org/pkg/genealogytree) package:
[image]

I've got most of the way there except for the fact that the "brother" and one of the "cousin" boxes overlap:
[image]

Here's my MWE that produced the image above:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,landscape]{article}
\usepackage[top=4.5cm, bottom=4.5cm, left=1cm, right=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}
\begin{document}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\genealogytree[template=signpost, id suffix=@p]
{
 child{
  g[male]{paternal grandfather}
  p[female]{paternal grandmother}
  child{
   g[male]{paternal uncle}
   c[male]{cousin}
   child{
    g[female]{cousin}
    }
   }
  child{
   g[female]{paternal aunt}
   c[male]{cousin}
   child{
    g[female]{cousin}
    }
   }
   child[phantom*]{
    g[male,id=father]{father}
    p[female]{mother}
    c[male]{brother}
    c{\textsc{ego}}
    c[female]{sister}
   }
 }
}
\genealogytree[template=signpost, id suffix=@m, set position=father@m at father@p]
{
 child{
  g[male]{maternal grandfather}
  p[female]{maternal grandmother}
  child{
   p[male,id=father]{father}
   g[female]{mother}
   child{
    g[male]{brother}
    c[male]{nephew}
    child{
     g[female]{niece}
    }
   }
   child{
    g{\textsc{ego}}
    c[male]{son}
    child{
     g[female]{daughter}
    }
   }
   child{
    g[female]{sister}
    c[male]{nephew}
    child{
     g[female]{niece}
    }
   }
  }
  child{
   g[male]{maternal uncle}
   c[male]{cousin}
   c[female]{cousin}
  }
  child{
   g[female]{maternal aunt}
   c[male]{cousin}
   c[female]{cousin}
  }
 }
}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

Help finding a solution would be welcome!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is true that you can manually shift the paternal tree...but the problem you are facing is solved in another way.

The issue is that in the paternal tree, you have termination at *only* the `brother`, `ego`, and `sister` nodes.  But in the maternal tree, you have `son`, `daughter`, and `niece`/`nephew` nodes terminating.  These lower-level nodes force more separation space between `brother`, `ego`, and `sister` -- this space is *not* required in the paternal tree, because those lower-level nodes don't exist.

All you need to do is mirror the *entire* child nodes structure from `father` and `mother` downward, like such:

EDIT:

The structure requires a very small tweak when you copy and paste.  The first image shows what happens when you do not make the tweak.  You'll need to flip the `g` and `p` in the `father` and `mother` nodes within the paternal tree.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,landscape]{article}
\usepackage[top=4.5cm, bottom=4.5cm, left=1cm, right=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}
\begin{document}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\genealogytree[template=signpost, id suffix=@p]
{
 child{
  g[male]{paternal grandfather}
  p[female]{paternal grandmother}
  child{
   g[male]{paternal uncle}
   c[male]{cousin}
   child{
    g[female]{cousin}
    }
   }
  child{
   g[female]{paternal aunt}
   c[male]{cousin}
   child{
    g[female]{cousin}
    }
   }
%OLD WAY
   %child[phantom*]{
    %g[male,id=father]{father}
    %p[female]{mother}
    %c[male]{brother}
    %c{\textsc{ego}}
    %c[female]{sister}
   %}
%MIRRORED FROM MATERNAL TREE (SEE FIRST IMAGE)
   %child[phantom*]{
   %p[male,id=father]{father}
   %g[female]{mother}
   %child{
    %g[male]{brother}
    %c[male]{nephew}
    %child{
     %g[female]{niece}
    %}
   %}
   %child{
    %g{\textsc{ego}}
    %c[male]{son}
    %child{
     %g[female]{daughter}
    %}
   %}
   %child{
    %g[female]{sister}
    %c[male]{nephew}
    %child{
     %g[female]{niece}
    %}
   %}
  %}
 %}
%MIRRORED FROM MATERNAL TREE WITH THE TWEAK (SEE SECOND IMAGE)
   child[phantom*]{
   g[male,id=father]{father}
   p[female]{mother}
   child{
    g[male]{brother}
    c[male]{nephew}
    child{
     g[female]{niece}
    }
   }
   child{
    g{\textsc{ego}}
    c[male]{son}
    child{
     g[female]{daughter}
    }
   }
   child{
    g[female]{sister}
    c[male]{nephew}
    child{
     g[female]{niece}
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
\genealogytree[template=signpost, id suffix=@m, set position=father@m at father@p]
{
 child{
  g[male]{maternal grandfather}
  p[female]{maternal grandmother}
  child{
   p[male,id=father]{father}
   g[female]{mother}
   child{
    g[male]{brother}
    c[male]{nephew}
    child{
     g[female]{niece}
    }
   }
   child{
    g{\textsc{ego}}
    c[male]{son}
    child{
     g[female]{daughter}
    }
   }
   child{
    g[female]{sister}
    c[male]{nephew}
    child{
     g[female]{niece}
    }
   }
  }
  child{
   g[male]{maternal uncle}
   c[male]{cousin}
   c[female]{cousin}
  }
  child{
   g[female]{maternal aunt}
   c[male]{cousin}
   c[female]{cousin}
  }
 }
}

\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

(without the tweak - a pure copy-and-paste):

[image: Proper merge of paternal and maternal trees in genealogytree without tweak]

(copy-and-paste plus switching `g` and `p` on `father` and `mother` nodes):

[image: Proper merge of paternal and maternal trees in genealogytree with tweak]

I think this way is preferable because of the automatic spacing.  The manual shift method should be reserved for what [the `genealogytree` manual on page 44 refers to](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/genealogytree/genealogytree.pdf) (which I think does not apply here):

> Note that in a more complicated situation more manual intervention may
>   be necessary to avoid unwanted overlapping of other nodes.

Comment: Something missing: the paternal relatives are connected with the mother, instead of the father

Comment: @CarLaTeX Ah, good catch!  There's a very small tweak that fixes the copy-and-paste approach.  I'll update it now.

Comment: Will this code work if I have 8 third-great-grandparents, 10 fourth-grandparents and fifth-great-grandparents, and 8 sixth-great-grandparents, @whatisit and @CarLaTeX?

Comment: @Oo'- I think you should adapt it

Answer (score 4):

You could use `tikz={xshift=...}` to shift the paternal relatives.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,landscape]{article}
\usepackage[top=4.5cm, bottom=4.5cm, left=1cm, right=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}
\begin{document}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\genealogytree[template=signpost, id suffix=@p]
{
 child{
  g[male]{paternal grandfather}
  p[female]{paternal grandmother}
  child{
   g[male,tikz={xshift=-2.3cm}]{paternal uncle}
   c[male,tikz={xshift=-2.3cm}]{cousin}
   child{
    g[female,tikz={xshift=-2.3cm}]{cousin}
    }
   }
  child{
   g[female,tikz={xshift=-2.3cm}]{paternal aunt}
   c[male,tikz={xshift=-2.3cm}]{cousin}
   child{
    g[female,tikz={xshift=-2.3cm}]{cousin}
    }
   }
   child[phantom*]{
    g[male,id=father]{father}
    p[female]{mother}
    c[male]{brother}
    c{\textsc{ego}}
    c[female]{sister}
   }
 }
}
\genealogytree[template=signpost, id suffix=@m, set position=father@m at father@p]
{
 child{
  g[male]{maternal grandfather}
  p[female]{maternal grandmother}
  child{
   p[male,id=father]{father}
   g[female]{mother}
   child{
    g[male]{brother}
    c[male]{nephew}
    child{
     g[female]{niece}
    }
   }
   child{
    g{\textsc{ego}}
    c[male]{son}
    child{
     g[female]{daughter}
    }
   }
   child{
    g[female]{sister}
    c[male]{nephew}
    child{
     g[female]{niece}
    }
   }
  }
  child{
   g[male]{maternal uncle}
   c[male]{cousin}
   c[female]{cousin}
  }
  child{
   g[female]{maternal aunt}
   c[male]{cousin}
   c[female]{cousin}
  }
 }
}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]