# is it possible to build `genealogytree` commands to build until 7 generations?

Tags: genealogytree, genealogy

I know perfectly that `parent{}` helps a lot, but it does not allow me to add the uncle's or aunt's spouse, and their children, etc. Of course that I can create many `genealogytree[]{}`, but it forces me to continually change the `xshift` position, what is tedious.

Only `child{}` can help, but I do not know if it is possible to make multiple suffixes. I know how to make `child{}` with father's and mother's genealogies, like I saw on https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/466112/172831.

But I want to add great-grandparents from both my grandfather's maternal and paternal sides, and also from my grandmother. I also would like to add the great-grandparents' maternal and paternal parents that are my third-time-great-grandparents.

Let me say that I have 8 third-great-grandparents, 10 fourth-grandparents and fifth-great-grandparents, and 8 sixth-great-grandparents.

Is it possible on `genealogytree`'s `child{}`?

Hastily and sillily, I copied and pasted the same code, and adapted a small code about my grandmother's genealogy:

```tex
\documentclass[a4paper,landscape]{article}
\usepackage[top = 4.5cm, bottom = 4.5cm, left = 1cm, right = 1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}

\begin{document}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}
{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \genealogytree
        [template = signpost, id suffix = @p ]
        {
            child
            {
                g[male]{paternal great-grandfather}
                p[female]{paternal great-grandmother}
                child
                {
                    g[male]{paternal grandfather}
                    p[female id = diva ]{paternal grandmother}
                    child
                    {
                            g[male]{paternal uncle}
                            c[male]{cousin}
                            child
                            {
                                    g[female]{cousin}
                            }
                    }
                    child
                    {
                            g[female]{paternal aunt}
                            c[male]{cousin}
                            child
                            {
                                g[female]{cousin}
                            }
                    }
                    child[phantom*]
                    {
                        g[male,id=father]{father}
                        p[female]{mother}
                        child
                        {
                            g[male]{brother}
                            c[male]{nephew}
                            child
                            {
                                g[female]{niece}
                            }
                        }
                        child
                        {
                            g{\textsc{ego}}
                            c[male]{son}
                            child
                            {
                                g[female]{daughter}
                            }
                        }
                        child
                        {
                            g[female]{sister}
                            c[male]{nephew}
                            child
                            {
                                g[female]{niece}
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } % end of child: paternal grandparents
            }
        }
        \genealogytree[template = signpost, id suffix = @m, set position = father@m at father@p]
        {
            child
            {
                g[male]{maternal grandfather}
                p[female]{maternal grandmother}
                child
                {
                    p[male, id = father]{father}
                    g[female]{mother}
                    child
                    {
                        g[male]{brother}
                        c[male]{nephew}
                        child
                        {
                                g[female]{niece}
                        }
                    }
                    child
                    {
                        g{\textsc{ego}}
                        c[male]{son}
                        child
                        {
                            g[female]{daughter}
                        }
                    }
                    child
                    {
                        g[female]{sister}
                        c[male]{nephew}
                        child
                        {
                                g[female]{niece}
                        }
                    }
                }
                child
                {
                    g[male]{maternal uncle}
                    c[male]{cousin}
                    c[female]{cousin}
                }
                child
                {
                    g[female]{maternal aunt}
                    c[male]{cousin}
                    c[female]{cousin}
                }
            }
        }

    \genealogytree[template = signpost, id suffix = @d, set position = diva@d at diva@p]
    {
        child
        {
            g[male]{paternal great-grandfather}
            p[female]{paternal great-grandmother}
            child
            {
                g[female, id = diva]{paternal grandmother}
            }
        }
    }
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd be interested to see answers to this. I tried to use this package quite a while ago and got so far, but no further. I couldn't figure out how to extend beyond a certain point. There always seemed to be constraints.

Comment: @cfr, thomas-f-sturm informed: “In general, genealogytree supports tree structures with some extensions, but it cannot do arbitrary mesh structures. Sorry.” :-/